# Date time Slot from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table "timeslot"

```
max students for timeslot 20
1= All slots booked
0= slots are vacant

batch_datetime       class_strength is_booked
2021-07-16 16:30:00    20               1
2021-07-16 10:00:00    15               0
2021-07-15 12:30:00    10               1
```

The issue I have to show date booked when all slots of this date is booked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store how many spaces are booked within each session, rather than just a yes/no indication of whether it's full? Otherwise you won't know how many more places you can provide in each session.

Comment: Also your requirement is unclear - are you looking to show whether every space in every session for a specific day is fully booked, or just show each session separately? Please provide a table showing the expected result of your query, for clarity. And have you tried anything to solve this yourself before asking for help? Please demonstrate your effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do you need in

```sql
SELECT DATE(batch_datetime) `date with all slots booked`
FROM timeslot
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(is_booked) = SUM(is_booked);
```

?

Comment: Yes but its giving only one row

Comment: Add sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO into your question, and desired output for this data.